# Refresh page after hitting the back button on widonws phone 7

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone application. It's some kind of reminder which can have custom reminder categories. I am using the mvvm pattern.

I have two pages. One is for entering new data (category name and description) and editing and the other is for selecting a specific category wchich can then be edited/deleted.

The second page has a listbox which displays all categories that exist... after clicking on one of them the first page where the values (category name and description) are already entered in the textboxes. I can now edit and save them. All this works fine except for one thing. After saving and hitting the back button (so that i can get back to the list) i realize that the page isnt refreshing so that the old value is still displayed. How can i make the page "refresh" after poping up again...

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is a bit vague without any code or XAML. There are few things you need to check -

1. Check if the items in the page are databound properly
2. Check if you have implemented properties of the ViewModel(s) correctly. RaisePropertyChanged in the property's setter must be implemented.

Code/XAML snippets will help others identify your problem.